# Should .sitecore folder get comitted to source control

Tags: sitecore-cli

Im developing my first Sitecore 10 site. I have installed the Sitecore CLI. This creates a folder in my project '.sitecore' with my CLI configuration, etc... Does this folder get committed to source control? Or is this entirely unique to each user?

Comment: You should not commit .sitecore folder. Please note it has user.json file which has sensitive data to connect to your Sitecore instance. When you restore the Sitecore CLI and authenticate, this folder will be created with necessary plugins and user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice some new files in your solution folder after the CLI installation process – e.g. `.scindex` files, .`sitecore/` folder. These can be added to `.gitignore`.

If you run into issues with your serialization after doing this, try running:

```
dotnet tool restore
```

The dotnet tool restore command will find the tool manifest file that is in scope for the current directory and install back the tools that are listed in it.

**Note:** Make sure not to commit the `.sitecore\user.json` file to source control as it contains privileged information.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can commit schema files in it. But add **.sitecore/package-cache** and **.sitecore/user.json** to .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to write the following things in your `.gitignore` file. That will prevent the user config information from committing to your solution.

```
# may contain OAuth secrets, do not commit
.sitecore/user.json

# NuGet cache for Sitecore CLI
.sitecore/package-cache/
```

Hope this helps.